# Navicat set default character set

Tags: navicat

The default character set, when creating a new database in Navicat, is latin1.

How can I change the default into utf8 with default collation utf8_general_ci?

Answer (score 0):

Change the my.cnf

```
cat /etc/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = innodb
character-set-server = utf8 
transaction-isolation = read-committed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about navicat, but about mysql settings.
mysql.you can change the **default-character-set=latin1** location in the ini file to **default-character-set=utf8** and then try it **by restarting mysql**.